# Worker stopping at first item reading from queue.Queue

Tags: python

I am trying to understand how Queue works

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

q = Queue()

urls = ['http://www.linkedin.com', 'http://www.amazon.com', 'http://www.facebook.com', 'http://www.uber.com']

def worker():
    item = q.get()
    print(item)
    q.task_done()

for i in range(1):
    t = Thread(target=worker)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

for url in urls:
    q.put(url)

q.join()
```

I was expecting it to print out all of the URL's but only the first one is being printed out.

I thought that the `worker` would get the first item, print it out, then go back to grab the next item. In this case, I'm just creating 1 thread but can add more threads once I understand what is going on.

Why is it only printing the first URL?

Comment: How would it ever print more than one? `range(1)` starts only one thread, and your workers each only process one item before they exit. Either run a loop inside the worker so it'll take another item off when it's done with the first one, or start more threads.

Comment: ok, maybe I misunderstood how this works. I thought the way a que works is that the worker will keep checking the thread if more items exist and keep working through them. It seems its only performing the task one time? How do I tell it to keep working through until the list is empty?

Comment: Put a `for` loop inside the worker function, if you want your worker to process multiple items. The queue is just a datastructure, it doesn't magically change your worker function to act like it has a loop if you didn't write one.

Comment: if I want to create more workers, with the for loop, will they "share" the list and cycle through it?

Comment: "Cycle through it" has some untrue connotations, so I don't want to affirm your above statement without clarifications about exactly what you meant by your choice of terminology, but they'll behave properly -- each worker will take one item at a time, no item will be grabbed by multiple workers, etc.

Comment: I see. People have used `while True` to handle that. I understand it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your worker only runs its code once -- grabbing one item from the queue, printing it, then exiting. To grab everything: you'll need a loop.

Since you've started this thread as a daemon, it's easy to just loop forever. You're essentially spinning off a thread that says "Grab something out of the queue if there's something there. If not, wait 'till there is. Print that thing, then repeat until the program exits."

```
def worker():
    while True:
        item = q.get()
        print(item)
        q.task_done()
```

What a queue is usually used for is either an easy FIFO stack (for which you could arguably recommend `collections.deque` in its place) or as a means of coordinating a whole group of workers to do distributed work. Imagine you have a group of 4:

```
NUM_WORKERS = 4

for _ in range(NUM_WORKERS):
    t = Thread(daemon=True, target=worker)
    t.start()
```

and wanted to handle a whole bunch of items

```
for i in range(1, 1000001):
    # 1..1000000
    q.put(i)
```

Now the work will be distributed among all four workers, without any worker grabbing the same item as another. This serves to coordinate your concurrency.